# How can I create a multiline, multicolumn list item layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, listviewitem, android-relativelayout

I am creating a messaging app and am currently working on the inbox. I'm using a `RecyclerView` to display the list of conversations and would like each list item to look like this:

[image]

1. Leftmost is the contact image at 90dp x 90dp
2. The first row has two columns--the contact name and the date. The date should *not* be a fixed size as I currently have it, but fit at most DD/MM/YYYY (can be smaller in the case of something like "Sunday") and should be anchored to the right margin. The contact(s) should expand as necessary to fill any space up to the date.
3. The second row contains as much text of the last message as will fit.

I was going to use `layout_weight` but that doesn't work in a `RelativeLayout` (and doesn't allow the contact names to elongate in the case of a shorter date) and `LinearLayout` doesn't let me use `layout_toEndOf`. I'm a newbie at Android development so I'm not sure if one of those is the "right" answer.

What's the proper way of accomplishing the layout I'm looking for?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/conversation_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/conversation_image_layout"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_name"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_contact_font_size"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/conversation_image_layout" />    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_date"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/conversation_contact_name"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_date_font_size" />    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_snippet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/conversation_contact_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_snippet_font_size"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/conversation_image_layout" />

    </RelativeLayout>    

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is what a list item currently looks like (I haven't loaded contact images yet). It's fine for the most part (though my layout code is probably incredibly bloated so I'd appreciate if anyone could point out ways to make it more concise) but notice how the date isn't on the same level as the contact name and wraps:

[image]

Comment: Are you still having the issue?

Comment: Nope, fixed it. I appreciate your response, but, uh...everything I read told me *not* to do anything you said ;)

I managed to solve it with a single RelativeLayout

Comment: Cool... whatever works for ya :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After it became clear to me that some of the layout parameters didn't mean what I thought they did, I spent some more time looking at my choices.

It is **not** recommended to nest LinearLayouts/use `layout_weight` within a list item, as the number of views created increases rapidly as more items are added. I managed to minify my code and keep it in a single RelativeLayout with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/conversation_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_image"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_contact_font_size"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/conversation_contact_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/conversation_contact_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_date_font_size"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_snippet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/conversation_contact_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_snippet_font_size"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/conversation_contact_image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notable changes:

- No nested tags - It was unnecessary to group the first line in its own layout
- Used `layout_alignBaseline` - @Vucko pointed out that I was using `marginTop` on the contact name but not the date. Even after removing it, the two were still misaligned. `android:gravity` had no effect and it turns out none of these actually affect the text inside the layout
- Used `layout_alignParentEnd` to fix the date issue. I've realized that in my case, a layout component usually only needs to reference one other in order to properly align itself relative to the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

One of the textView in question has the MarginTop attribute, and the other one doesn't. Either remove it on both or add it to both:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_contact_name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_contact_font_size"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/conversation_image_layout" />    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_date"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/conversation_contact_name"
        android:gravity="right"

        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/conversations_date_font_size" />
```

Also, I'd recommend that you use Linear Layouts with nested Linear Layouts and weights, for better performance on different screens and devices. This may all fall apart if you run it on a different device. Don't trust me, try it :)

Comment: Trying it right now. Are you sure about the performance gain though?
From [the developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html): 

"This [LinearLayout] layout works but can be wasteful if you instantiate it for every list item of a ListView. The same layout can be rewritten using a single RelativeLayout, thus saving one view, and even better one level in view hierarchy, per list item."

Comment: I am not sure, I just know that I've had dreadful experience with Relative layouts because they simply don't scale well to different devices. If they work for you, by all means, use them.